# Oracle Invalid identifier error after renaming a column name

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-data

I have a table (let's call it MY_TABLE) with a column (let's call it COLUMN_A).

I use spring Data to execute CRUD operations on that table. Especially, I use `save` method from `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository` interface to insert some logging data into that table.

My issue is that, I noticed this morning that while creating MY_TABLE (using an SQL script), I made a typo and wrote `COLUM_NA` instead of `COLUMN_A` as column name.

So I `ALTER`ed the table to rename that column, then I renamed the column name in my Java entity class `MyTableEntity` and into the getter/setter methods as well.

Since then, when I execute my Java application I have this Oracle error:

```
ORA-00904: "MYTABLEENT0_"."COLUMN_A" : invalid identifier.
```

It’s like he’s not finding the new column name and still using the old wrong one. But I don’t know why, I’ve changed the column name everywhere.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please show us the Java code and `ALTER` statement.

Comment: `RENAME` column [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d083/1)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ALTER TABLE MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE
RENAME COLUMN COLUM_NA TO COLUMN_A;

Comment: @VR46 I already renamed the column as I said, why renaming it again ?

Comment: @Siho - I was showing you a demo. After renaming I can use the new column name. Did u check that

Comment: @VR46 Ah ok sorry. I saw your demo. So considering that the problem may be in spring data, maybe I have to do "some other stuff" to make it consider the new name (since I'm executing my insert query from my java app)

Comment: @Siho - yep :) exactly

Comment: @VR46 do you have any suggestion to fix the problem then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I'm so confused. I just realized that I executed my `ALTER` request on the **wrong database** (I have many databases with approximately the same tables).

So it’s logic that it still use the wrong name while inserting, since the column name still wrong in **that (good) database**. After `ALTER`ing the table in the good database, my app (and especially my `INSERT` request) went well.

Sorry and thank you all for your answers and comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you look carefully at the error message, you'll notice something about how the column_name is displayed.

```
ORA-00904: "MYTABLEENT0_"." COLUMN_A " : invalid identifier.
                           ^         ^
```

There are rogue spaces there.  Probably your actual column is called `COLUMN_A` with no spaces.  Oracle treats identifiers in double quotes as literals.  Consequently `" COLUMN_A " != "COLUMN_A"`.

You can problably fix this by editing your configuration file.

Comment: Thank you APC, but I manually changed the column name while writing my question (for confidentiality concerns) and while doing this I introduced spaces whithout realizing it. I edited my question. In the real error mesage there is no space I've just checked. But thank you for the clue